# Why is my Angular ng-model composite value not updating?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I haven't used JavaScript in six years, so I'm brushing up on it and learning Angular at the same time via W3Schools. This means I'm likely doing multiple things wrong here, so bear with me.

In my code below, I would expect that `rgb` would update to the composite of `red`, `green`, and `blue` as I move the input sliders. However, the DIV with `background: #{{rgb}};` doesn't render at all, so it's obviously unhappy.

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
<title>Color Mixer</title>
<style>
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 255px;
    height: 25px;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="font-family: verdana;">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <h1>Color Mixer</h1>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="128" class="slider" style="background: #880000;" ng-model="red"></br>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="128" class="slider" style="background: #008800;" ng-model="green"></br>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="128" class="slider" style="background: #000088;" ng-model="blue"></br>

    <div style="width: 256px; height: 25px; margin: 1px; text-align: center;" ng-model="rgb">
        {{
            red.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, "0") +
            green.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, "0") +
            blue.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, "0")
        }}
    </div>

    <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; margin: 1px; background: #{{rgb}};">
    </div>

    <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; margin: 1px; background: #{{red.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, \"0\") + green.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, \"0\") + blue.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, \"0\")}};">
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
});
</script>

</html>
```

You can see that I also added a second attempt at a background-colored DIV using `padStart()` with character-escaped double-quotes; it also does not render.

Finally, I added the controller even though it's empty. I tried assigning the value of `rgb` there, but it wouldn't let me access `red`, `green`, or `blue`.

Why is my Angular ng-model composite value (`rgb`) not updating?

Comment: Even though I can't reply to your question but I have a question for you, why would you learn angularjs in 2021.

Comment: I'm looking at this on mobile, but some things that stand out: ng-model is not available on all elements. It's typically available on input elements to give the two-way binding you need. I don't think it would do anything on a div. You probably want an ng-change on your inputs and have that calculate the rgb scope value. Finally, I think you'll probably want ngStyle rather than style.

Comment: @IsmailDinar, I'm learning it because my company uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` will not work with divs and `style` syntax on the other divs is invalid.

You could use `ng-style` to achieve what you want with rgb values:

```
ng-style="{ 'background-color': 'rgb('+red+', '+green+', '+blue+')' }"
```

Check here a working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xs1rzwbL/)

Comment: Thanks, Bill P.

I was also able to get it to work by HTML character-escaping the double quotes with "&quot;":

`<div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; margin: 1px; background: #{{red.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, &quot;0&quot;) + green.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, &quot;0&quot;) + blue.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, &quot;0&quot;)}};"></div>`